# comma question when a part leaded by the preposition "as" is set off by commas

Tags: commas

1. A high demand for AI technology as a means of solving complex problems is expected.
2. A high demand for AI technology, as a means of solving complex problems, is expected.

I have four questions on whether it's okay to add commas into sentence A to set off the part "as...problems" with commas.

Q1) If I consider "as...problems" as non-essential information, can I set off the part "as...problems" with commas?

Q2) Even though there are commas in 2, is "a means" still referring to "AI technology", not "A high demand" ?

Q3) If I consider AI technology will be used only for solving complex problems, is sentence 2 the correct one, not sentence 1, because the part "as...problems" restricts the category of AI technology by modifying it?

Q4) Have you ever seen "as" part set off by commas like in 2, in an English book or writing?

Could you please answer my four questions one by one?

Comment: "As a means of solving complex problems" is complement of "demand" and hence should not be set apart from the rest  of the clause by punctuation such as commas.

Comment: @BillJ, do you mean if the part is set off by commas, it is the complement of demand ? But would no one think that way because it's nonsense to think of a means as referring to "demand".